# Python re.findall() is not working as expected

Tags: python, regex

I have the code:

```
import re
sequence="aabbaa"
rexp=re.compile("(aa|bb)+")
rexp.findall(sequence)
```

This returns `['aa']`

If we have

```
import re
sequence="aabbaa"
rexp=re.compile("(aa|cc)+")
rexp.findall(sequence)
```

we get `['aa','aa']`

Why is there a difference and why (for the first) do we not get `['aa','bb','aa']`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

let me explain what you are doing:

```
regex = re.compile("(aa|bb)+")
```

you are creating a regex which will look for `aa` or `bb` and then will try to find if there are more `aa` or `bb` after that, and it will keep looking for `aa` or `bb` until it doesnt find. since you want your capturing group to return only the `aa` or `bb` then you only get the last captured/found group.

however, if you have a string like this: `aaxaabbxaa` you will get `aa,bb,aa` because you first look at the string and find `aa`, then you look for more, and find only an `x`, so you have 1 group. then you find another `aa`, but then you find a `bb`, and then an `x` so you stop and you have your second group which is `bb`. then you find another `aa`. and so your final result is `aa,bb,aa`

i hope this explains what you are DOING. and it is as expected. to get ANY group of `aa` or `bb` you need to remove the `+` which is telling the regex to seek multiple groups before returning a match. and just have regex return each match of `aa` or `bb`...

so your regex should be:

```
regex = re.compile("(aa|bb)")
```

cheers.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I couldn't figure this out at all.

Comment: Not related: When you're flagging answers, instead of "Very Low Quality", could you flag them as "Not An Answer"?  It helps us tremendously when processing those flags.  Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

The unwanted behaviour comes down to the way you formulate regualar expression:

```
rexp=re.compile("(aa|bb)+")
```

Parentheses `(aa|bb)` forms a group.

And if we look at the [docs of findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) we will see this:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. **If one** or more groups are **present in the pattern**,
>   **return a list of groups**; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of another match.**

As you formed a group, it mathced first `aa`, then `bb`, then `aa` again (because of `+` quantifier). So this group holds `aa` in the end. And `findall` returns this value in the list `['aa']` (as there is only one match `aabbaa` of the whole expression, the list contains only one element `aa` which is saved in the group).

From the code you gave, you seemed to want to do this:

```
>>> rexp=re.compile("(?:aa|bb)+")
>>> rexp.findall(sequence)
['aabbaa']
```

`(?: ...)` doesnt create any group, so `findall` returns the match of the whole expression.

In the end of your question you show the desired output. This is achieved by just looking for `aa` or `bb`. No quantifiers (`+` or `*`) are needed. Just do it the way is in the Inbar Rose's answer:

```
>>> rexp=re.compile("aa|bb")
>>> rexp.findall(sequence)
['aa', 'bb', 'aa']
```

Comment: i tried wording this in a horribly convoluted way, nice way of explaining it clearly. :) and +1 for quoting the docs. :)

Answer (score 0):

your pattern

```
rexp=re.compile("(aa|bb)+")
```

matches the whole string aabbaa. to clarify just look at this

```
>>> re.match(re.compile("(aa|bb)+"),"aabbaa").group(0)
'aabbaa'
```

Also no other substrings are to match then

```
>>> re.match(re.compile("(aa|bb)+"),"aabbaa").group(1)
'aa'
```

so a findall will return the one substring only

```
>>> re.findall(re.compile("(aa|bb)+"),"aabbaa")
['aa']
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not understand why you use **+** - it means 0 or 1 occurrence, and is usually used when you want find string with optional inclusion of substring.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(aa|bb)', 'aabbaa')
['aa', 'bb', 'aa']
```

work as expected

Comment: No `+`does not mean 0 or 1, that would be `?`. `+` means 1 or more.

Comment: your logic is wrong, but your answer is correct. `+` means `one or more matches` while `?` means `matches one or no matches` . i have no idea what you mean by "usually used when you want find string with optional inclusion of substring." but its misleading. the answer is, if you want to capture a group with optional values, you do as you answered above. including a `+` in the regex causes it to seek multiple capturing groups and return only the last one he catches. if they are concurrent/following eachother.

Comment: OK, got me here. Haven't used RE for a while - too heavy for my purpose.