# Multiple regex patterns to extract data from article using python

Tags: python, regex

New to python but old to living.
I attempting to use multiple regex patterns from a txt file to extract data from a news article, txt file.  I have gotten it to a point where I can find matches but not save the extracted data.  This is what I have in raw unhygienic nonpythonic script so far.  I appreciate all comments as I am self learning.

```
import re

reg_ex = open('APT1.txt', "r", encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
lines = reg_ex.read()
strip = lines.strip()
reggie = strip.split(';') 


reggie_lst = []
match_lst = []

for raw_regex in reggie:
    reggie_lst.append(re.compile(raw_regex))


get_string = open("APT.txt", "r", encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
nystring = get_string.read()


if any(compiled_reg.search(nystring) for compiled_reg in reggie_lst):
    print("Got some Matches")
```

Comment: What do you want to extract? All the matches of all your regex in the list? It would be better if you provide a simple example and expected outcome. And also please make clear what is the question you're asking.

Comment: Sit in a loop, like a for loop on the compiled regexes. Do some kind of a findall using the regex and the input. So, each pass gets some array of data that you can save to a permanent location.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I want to extract all of the matches from the article which is in the APT.txt file.  I am asking how to capture this data (list of matching words) and place it into another txt file.  These words would be exact and derivatives of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall()` to **extract** your data into a list, instead of just asking if a regex has matched.

```
import re

reg_ex = open('APT1.txt', "r", encoding='utf-8-sig')
lines = reg_ex.read()
strip = lines.strip()
reggie = strip.split(';')

reggie_lst = []
match_lst = []

for raw_regex in reggie:
    reggie_lst.append(raw_regex)

get_string = open("APT.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8-sig')
nystring = get_string.read()


for reg in reggie_lst:
    for text_match in re.findall(reg, nystring):
        print("Got match for regex {}: {}".format(reg, text_match))
```

Instead of printing it in the last line you can also save it in  a new file, of course. In this example I have also removed compiling the regex only for printing/debugging purposes.

Caution by using parentheses (groups) in your regex. The `re.findall()` behaviour is a little bit different to `re.search()` or `re.match()`. You have to use `(?: …` then, see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12999616/2648551).

Comment: Thank you.  I have far to go and a lot of reading to do.  This has gotten me beyond a sticking point.  It is much appreciated.