# python regex - findall not returning output as expected

Tags: python, python-re

I am having trouble understanding findall, which says...

```
Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.
```

Why doesn't this basic IP regex work with findall as expected? The matches are not overlapping, and regexpal confirms that pattern is highlighted in re_str.

[image]

Expected: ['1.2.2.3', '123.345.34.3']

Actual:   ['2.', '34.']

```
re_str = r'(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}'
line = 'blahblah -- 1.2.2.3 blah 123.345.34.3'
matches = re.findall(re_str, line)
print(matches)    # ['2.', '34.']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python re.findall() is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999419/python-re-findall-is-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use parentheses in your regex, `re.findall()` will return only the parenthesized groups, not the entire matched string. Put a `?:` after the `(` to tell it not to use the parentheses to extract a group, and then the results should be the entire matched string.

Answer (score 1):

This is because capturing groups return only the last match if they're repeated.

Instead, you should make the repeating group non-capturing, and use a non-repeated capture at an outer layer:

```py
re_str = r'((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})'
```

Note that for `findall`, if there is no capturing group, the whole match is automatically selected (like `\0`), so you could drop the outer capture:

```py
re_str = r'(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}'
```